# Fetch data with SWR on client component with each request. Next.js 13.3 + SWR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Next.js 13.3 with app dir. I have a very simple component that displays a date. He displays it only 1 time and after that it is no longer updated until I rebuild it. In Next.js 12, this worked differently (refresh page - update data). What am I doing wrong? I can't figure out how to make it update the date on every request.

Why doesn't SWR update information on every request?

**api/hello/route.ts**

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  // const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);

  const response = await fetch(
    "https://timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=Europe/Kiev",
    { cache: "no-cache" }
  );

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);

  return NextResponse.json(data);
}
```

**time.tsx**

```
"use client";

import useSWR from "swr";
import { fetcher } from "~/lib/fetcher";

export const Time = () => {
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR("api/hello", fetcher);

  if (error) {
    return <div>error</div>;
  }

  if (isLoading) return <div>loading...</div>;

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{data.dateTime}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**fetcher.ts**

```
export const fetcher = (...args: any) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())
```

**page.tsx**

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Time } from "~/components/time";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const revalidate = 0;

export default async function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <Time />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is refreshing the time on page refresh (next: latest):

```
import useSWR, { SWRConfig } from "swr";
import { getTime } from "../lib/libTime";

const fetcher = (url: any) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export async function getStaticProps () {
    const mytime = await getTime()
    
    return {
      props: {
        fallback: {
          '/api/time': mytime
        }
      }
    }
  }
   
  function MyTime() {
    const { data } = useSWR('/api/time', fetcher)
    if (!data) return <>"Loading...";</>
    return (<><h1>{data.data.dateTime}</h1></>)
  }


const SWR=({ fallback }:any)=> {
  return (
    <SWRConfig value={{ fallback }}>
      <MyTime />
    </SWRConfig>
  );
}
export default SWR;
```